# change div1 on hover over div2 which is under div1

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Is it possible to change `div1` if `div2` is hovered but under `div1`?

```css
/* Works */
.div1:hover + .div2 {
  background-color: red;
}

/* Doesn't Work */
.div2:hover + .div1,
.div2:hover ~ .div1,
.div2:hover .div1 {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="div1">hover</div>
<div class="div2">hover</div>
```

Solutions using `Javascript` and/or `JQuery` are also appreciated

Comment: Nope, the CSS does not provide a provide a previous sibling selector, the only solution is using JS. You can use jquery's prev() method for the same.

Comment: It is possible by setting `pointer-events: none` for `div1`, but then hover events wont work for `div1`

Comment: I thought about that too @NitinSuri. Thats why I wrote: "Resolutions with Js and jQ are also appreciated" ;)

Comment: And also @Salar I want to use both ... `div1:hover` should change `div2` and `div2:hover` should change `div1`

Comment: check the answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `JQuery`'s [.hover()](https://api.jquery.com/hover/) + [.css()](http://api.jquery.com/css/) for both the divs

```js
$( ".div1" ).hover(
  function() {
    $(".div2").css( "background-color", "red" );
  }, function() {
    $(".div2").css( "background-color", "initial" );
  }
);

$( ".div2" ).hover(
  function() {
    $(".div1").css( "background-color", "red" );
  }, function() {
    $(".div1").css( "background-color", "initial" );
  }
);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="div1">hover</div>
<div class="div2">hover</div>
```

Comment: OP uses classes, which sole purpose is to be reusable - multiple on a single page. Yet you did not provided any notice about when your code will flawlessly fail.

Answer (score 1):

Nope, the CSS does not provide a provide a previous sibling selector, the only solution is using JS. You can use jquery's prev() method for the same.

```js
$(function() {
  $(".div2").hover(function() {
      $(this).prev().addClass("hoveredBg");
    },
    function() {
      $(this).prev().removeClass("hoveredBg");
    });
});
```

```css
.hoveredBg {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="div1">div 1 hover</div>
<div class="div2">div 2 hover</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

This will only help your hover for the previous sibling div only and not burden the browser for next sibling hover, which can be achieved using CSS only.

Comment: Upvoted for actually selecting the physically previous element - and not every possible `.div1` in the DOM. (although there is a more flexible way - but since that's the HTML we have from OP....)

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use javascript, you can use `display: flex` on the container, then change the rendering order (note that the html order has to be updated as well). Then you can hover on `div2` and highlight `div1`.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.div1, .div2 {
  flex: 0 0 100%;
}

.div1 { order: 1; }
.div2 { order: 2; }

.div2:hover ~ .div1 {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="div2">hover 2</div>
  <div class="div1">hover 1</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Good, actually amazing catch!

Answer (score 0):

Try this below code.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".div2").mouseover(function() {
    $(".div1").css("background-color", "red");
  });
  $(".div2").mouseout(function() {
    $(".div1").css("background-color", "");
  });
});
```

```css
/* Works */

.div1:hover+.div2 {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="div1">hover</div>
<div class="div2">hover</div>
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: .....There's almost no use for `mouseover/out`. And there's a huge difference. Use `mouseenter/leave` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this fiddle,

https://jsfiddle.net/rkqhvzyc/

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".div2").hover(function(){
      $('.div1').css("background-color", "red");
      }, function(){
      $('.div1').css("background-color", "white");
  });
});
```

```css
/* Works */
.div1:hover + .div2 {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="div1">hover</div>
<div class="div2">hover</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Interesting how nobody pointed out that **classes are multiple** on a single page,
 and no, you should not target `.div1` just like that, like many suggested, and expect that all other `.div1` in the DOM will not be targeted as-well.

```js
// NONSENSE
$( ".div2" ).hover(
  function() {
    $(".div1").css( "background-color", "red" );
  }, function() {
    $(".div1").css( "background-color", "initial" );
  }
);
```

```html
<div class="div1">DIV1</div>
<div class="div2">DIV2 hover me</div>
<div class="div1">DIV1</div>
<div class="div2">DIV2 hover me</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

To reflect the above-mentioned problem - here's **a couple of solutions:**

```js
// 1. EXAMPLE TARGETING .prev() (NOT FLEXIBLE)
$(".hoverTargetPrev").hover(function() {
  $(this).prev(".div1").toggleClass("red");
});

// 2. BETTER EXAMPLE USING .couple PARENT, .closest() AND .find()
$(".div2").hover(function() {
  $(this).closest(".couple").find(".div1").toggleClass("red");
});

// 3. EXAMPLE TARGETING .prevAll() and .eq(0) (a bit expensive but...)
$(".hoverTargetNearestPrev").hover(function() {
  $(this).prevAll(".div1").eq(0).toggleClass("red");
});
```

```css
.div2 {color:red;}
.red {background: red;}
```

```html
<h3> 1. EXAMPLE TARGETING .prev() (NOT FLEXIBLE)</h3>
<div class="div1">DIV1</div>
<div class="div2 hoverTargetPrev">DIV2 hover me</div>
<div class="div1">DIV1</div>
<div class="div2 hoverTargetPrev">DIV2 hover me</div>
<div class="div1">DIV1</div>
<div>Future intruder...</div>
<div class="div2 hoverTargetPrev">DIV2 hover me (will not work any more)</div>


<h3> 2. BETTER EXAMPLE USING .couple PARENT, .closest() AND .find() </h3>
<div class="couple">
  <div class="div1">DIV1</div>
  <div class="div2">DIV2 hover me</div>
</div>
<div class="couple">
  <div class="div1">DIV1</div>
  <div class="div2">DIV2 hover me</div>
</div>
<div class="couple">
  <div class="div1">DIV1</div>
  <div>Future intruder...</div>
  <div class="div2">DIV2 hover me (will kork!)</div>
</div>

<h3> 3. EXAMPLE TARGETING .prevAll() and .eq(0) (a bit expensive but...)</h3>
<div class="div1">DIV1</div>
<div class="div2 hoverTargetNearestPrev">DIV2 hover me</div>
<div class="div1">DIV1</div>
<div class="div2 hoverTargetNearestPrev">DIV2 hover me</div>
<div class="div1">DIV1</div>
<div>Future intruder...</div>
<div class="div2 hoverTargetNearestPrev">DIV2 hover me (will work!!)</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```